# How to I enter hours and minutes on my Samsung range?

Tags: kitchens

Why does the Cooking Time not allow me to enter hours?  All  I get is Minutes. What is that flashing arrow above where the digits are for the time?
No matter when I enter amm I can get is seconds or minutes for the maximum if the three digits I can enter.  Thanks for any help

Comment: At a minimum you'd want to include a model number, right?

Comment: So entering 1-3-0 doesn't get you 1 hour, 30 minutes?

Comment: Number of hours multiplied by sixty equals the number of minutes, i.e. hrs x 60 = mins, e.g. 2 hours 20 minutes is (2x60=120)+20 = 140 minutes.

Comment: @elrobis, I can't imagine any appliance maker requiring mental time conversion to use their product.

Comment: ...tongue-in-cheek. IMO this is a trivial, seemingly non-problem lol. That being said, I was *not* the down-voter

Comment: @Nancy if you can find your model number—it's probably on a tag or sticker stuck to the back near the electric wire—you should be able to lookup your owners manual here: https://www.samsung.com/us/support/home-appliances/ranges

Comment: My Samsung stove is model NE59J7750WS

Comment: If I enter 150 I get 1.50 minutes.  If I enter 500 I get 5 minutes.  If I enter 5 I get 5 minutes.  There is nothing on the display panel to show hr.  When I push the Cooking Time button this shows up: _ _ _ min. There is an arrow pointing to the right above this.  I can't push it or anything.  My problem is cannot set for say 5 hours. Samsung told me to enter 5 0 0, but I just get 5 minutes. There is no..... _ hr _ _ min.....like I have seen online in some pics.

Comment: @elrobis they hid the user manual under a "see more" button, that is not user friendly

Comment: Are you saying when you type 5 0 0 it displays `5 00 min`?  If you leave it run for 2 minutes, when you come back does it say `4 58 min` or does it say `3 00 min`?  Actually. Don't guess.

Answer (score 1):

According to the operator manual, entering a setting of 500 should result in 5 hours and 00 mins, not 5 mins as you are getting. That being said it should immediately display 4:59, as it is displaying a truncated 4:59:59.

Entering 120 should be 1 hour and 20 mins, not 2 hours, the 3rd digit to the left is always hours, but you can enter 90 and get 90 mins. The max cook timer is 9hrs 99 mins.

If it is literally treating the entered value as mins/secs instead of hrs/mins, take a video of this happening, and contact Samsung support.

[Direct link to english manual](http://downloadcenter.samsung.com/content/UM/201705/20170518105619625/NE59J7850WS_AA_DG68-00600A-05_EN-MES-CFR.pdf)

Comment: Page 27.  http://downloadcenter.samsung.com/content/UM/201705/20170518105619625/NE59J7850WS_AA_DG68-00600A-05_EN-MES-CFR.pdf

Comment: I have contacted Samsung 3 times and no one can help me.  No answers or help, they just say enter 5 0 0 for 5 hours but all I get is 5 minutes.  I have no hrs on the display.