# Using the cooking time on Samsung stove

Tags: kitchens

My Samsung stove is model NE59J7750WS – Nancy 1 hour ago   delete

If I enter 150 I get 1.50 minutes. If I enter 500 I get 5 minutes. If I enter 5 I get 5 minutes. There is nothing on the display panel to show hr. When I push the Cooking Time button this shows up: _ _ _ min. There is an arrow pointing to the right above this. I can't push it or anything. My problem is cannot set for say 5 hours. Samsung told me to enter 5 0 0, but I just get 5 minutes. There is no..... _ hr _ _ min.....like I have seen online in some pics. – Nancy 1 hour ago   delete

Comment: Please stop posting the same question over and over.  If you look at the bottom of your [original question](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/127034/how-to-i-enter-hours-and-minutes-on-my-samsung-range), you will see the words `share edit delete` ... please click `edit` and change your original post to include any new data.

Comment: Don't be so bossy.  I am new to this site.  If u don't have anything helpful to add, don't comment.

Answer (score 0):

Your control timer is clearly on its way out.  Sorry. Little to do but replace it. P.

Comment: The stove is new, have never used the cooking timer before.  Yikes...I will call a technician I guess.